# var currentWebsiteURL does not recognize the current pag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

My currentWebsiteURL:

var currentWebsiteURL =window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+window.location.pathname;

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Could you include a code snippet or somekind of scenario?

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because the regex clearly works (just tested it in console). You are simply trying to match consequent alphanumerical characters in URL, which probably contains also non alphanumerical characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following modifiers `gi`,

```
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

`i` is optional if you need your regex to be insensitive.

Currently, your code will look for the first match and stop.

So the code will be like

```
var s = currentWebsiteURL.match(/\w{17}/gi); 
window.alert(s);
```

**Update**

Note:

```
/\w{17}/gi
```

Means that it will split the string into chunks, each chunk is 17 character length.

If you want to get the variable with 17 chars or less, you should use the following regex:

```
/\w{0,17}/gi
```

If your variable contains other special characters like #, /, -. so you need to include them in your regex

Something like this:

```
/[\w\+\&\@\#\/\%\?\=\~\_\|\$\!\:\,\.\;\-\&\@\#\/\%\=\~\_]{17}/gi
```

Comment: I tried var s = currentWebsiteURL.match(/\w{17}/gi); 

It did not work.

Comment: Could you give me sample of your **currentWebsiteURL** variable

Comment: var currentWebsiteURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "//" + window.location.pathname + "//" + window.location.href + "//" +  window.location.assign;

Comment: No problem for him in the first occurrence, I'm actually looking for an exactly 34 character / \ w {34} /.
A wallet BTC. There is only one string that size in the text.

Comment: @developer +1 for your patience :)

Comment: Hmm, as i see, you work with a URL, you need to be care that urls will contains other special characters like **#**, **/**, **-**. so you need to include them in your regex like: **[\w\/\:\-\.\#]{17}**

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your URL simply doesn't contain 17 consequent alphanumerical characters. Compare:

```
 // Returns null
 "sssss.ssssssss.ssssss.sssss.ssss".match(/\w{17}/);

 // Returns ["sssssssssssssssss"]
 "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssss".match(/\w{17}/);
```

Reassess what you want to achieve, then try to make the correct regexp.

Comment: These characters I seek: 1dowHcSE6s0Ms0IZcEbO1zENtUJA3E2KSq.
They are in the file.
Sorry my English is very bad.

Comment: @Cylond'Sousa `"1dowHcSE6s0Ms0IZcEbO1zENtUJA3E2KSq".match(/\w{17}/);` returns `["1dowHcSE6s0Ms0IZc"]`. Your English is not a problem. The problem is you didn't provide all info about your problem. What are you trying to do? What is the **exact** string you're trying to match?

Comment: OK, I found the error. Tomáš Sato, is probably correct. I will solve and come back with the answer.

Comment: I want it: 1dowHcSE6s0Ms0IZcEbO1zENtUJA3E2KSq.

BTC wallets are all have the same pattern. But the problem that any string longer than 16 characters returns null.

In fact I want .match (/ \ w {34} /);

Comment: @Cylond'Sousa Look, either edit your original question so that it can be answered (curently it cannot be, because the problem is not clear) or find the solution yourself. To get an answer you should provide full info about your problem. I already demonstrated that the regexp works, so there is no problem with it. There are comprehensive instructions how to ask question properly here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Zato, currentWebsiteURL
current website URL, as you had predicted.
I'll change, but I have no idea how to redesign.

Comment: Now I understand. var s = currentWebsiteURL.match(/\w{17}/gi); 
 it only seeks the link.
I wanted to seek the body of the page.